# C# ?? operator not printing value if variable is null

Tags: c#

I have a class named Sample with a string property called Name, ToString() overridden to return Name property.

Then i have created two instances s1 and s2, s1 initialized and it's Name property set to "ABC" and s2 is set to null.

When i try to print the values using ?? operator of c#, value string "Null" is not printed for s2.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sample s1 = new Sample();
        s1.Name = "ABC";

        Sample s2 = null;

        Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + s1 ?? "Null");
        Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + s2 ?? "Null");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Sample 
{
    string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Some Sample Name : ABC
Some Sample Name :
```

Comment: [7.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: For my article on this common error, see http://blog.coverity.com/2013/10/23/null-coalescing-bugs/

Comment: Even without the precedence error, the `??` operator is simply the wrong operator to use here. The `??` operator means "use the value of the left hand side if it is not null, otherwise use the value of the right hand side", but that is not the meaning you are trying to represent here. You are trying to say "convert the left hand side to a string, but if it is null then use the right hand side", and that is a *different* operation. The `??` operator does not do that second operation. What you need is the `?:` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) issue, your code first does the `+`, combining the `"Some Sample Name : "` literal with `s1`, then applies `??` to that.

Since `s1` and `s2` are `Sample`, not `String`, you can't use `s1 ?? "Null"`. Probably the simplest thing is using the conditional operator:

```
Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + (s1 == null ? "Null" : s1.ToString()));
```